# Having difficulty constructing a Binary tree from a list of class instances

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, binary-tree

I'm trying to construct a KDtree for finding 'K nearest neighbour'
I've created a class called 'Point' which holds attributes: pointID, lat (latitude) and Lon (longitude).
the input for the build_index is an array 'points' contains all instances of points.

in the code below I'm trying to construct the KDtree but I'm having issues with trying to retrieve just the lat and Lon of each Point to sort, but I understand just using 'points' will not work as it is a an array with just the class instances.

thanks for the help in advance!

```
class KDTreeNN(NearestNeigh):

   def build_index(self, points: [Point]):
       depth = 0
       n = len(points)
       if n <0:
           return None
       axis = depth % 2
       sorted_points = sorted(points, key = lambda point: point[axis])
       depth + 1
       return {
           'point' : sorted_points[int(n/2)],
           'left' : self.build_index(sorted_points[:int(n/2)]),
           'right' : self.build_index(sorted_points[int(n/2) + 1:])
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`point[axis]` is not working because `point` does not support such bracket notation.

There are several solutions:

1. Define `Point` as a named tuple:

   Instead of defining `Point` as something like:

   ```
   class Point:
       def __init__(self, pointID, lat, lon):
           self.pointID = pointID
           self.lat = lat
           self.lon = lon
   ```

   ...define it as a named tuple. Make sure to make `lon` and `lat` its first two members:

   ```
   Point = namedtuple("Point", "lat,lon,pointID")
   ```

   Also ensure that were create `Point` instances, you put the arguments in the right order.

   With that change it will work. This requires that you treat `Point` instances as immutable.
2. Access the attribute (`lon` or `lat`) depending on a string variable:

   ```
   axis = ("lon", "lat")[depth % 2]
   sorted_points = sorted(points, key = lambda point: getattr(point, axis))
   ```